# jQuery Detect CSS Property Change

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to use jQuery to establish whether a CSS property has changed inside a class. I do npt want to use .HasClass() - I want to find a property within the CSS - namely

```
display:block;
```

I thought maybe this might work ?

```
if (jQuery('css-class').css('display') == 'block')
```

But not sure if it does.

Comment: it should work! If you are not sure, why don't you simply try it?

Comment: hi - sorry, yes i am travelling and didn't think this would work.

Comment: yeah it should be jQuery('.css-class')

Comment: Yep, that should work. Only suggestion: use === instead of == (just good practice)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's .css('css-property') function will return the value of the property, if it exists.
So, the check for display:block

```
if($('selector').css('display') == 'block')
```

does work.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you should replace `css-class` with a selector:

```
if (jQuery('#some_id').css('display') == 'block')
{
  // your code...
}
```

The code within `if` block will execute if the element with id `#some_id` has `display` set to `block`.